# Node.js + Loopback: Run remote hooks programmatically

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I need to programmatically run remote hooks for a model. How can I do that?

Comment: Wouldn't you just create a method in the model that does what you want it to do.  Remote hooks are called automatically before or after other methods.  I think you would have to create your own method to execute them by themselves.

Comment: I have a remote call in a model A, when I optionaly receive a model B. If the model B is provided I should create it. The model B creation request has remote hooks. Now, this hooks should be executed in two cases, when model B is created and when a request for model A is executed. I try to find a solution to avoid remote hooks code duplication

Comment: @MaximSharai I'm running into the same annoying issue. Did you find a solution for this other than duplicating code?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solutions and implemented mine

```
/**
 * Trigger execution of remote hooks of a model
 *
 * @param app The loopback application
 * @param modelName The model name
 * @param data The model data
 * @param when The possible values are 'before' or 'after'
 * @param method The remote method name
 * @param ctx The hooks context
 * @param next
 */
exports.execHooks = function(app, modelName, data, when, method, ctx, next) {

  // Save original context values
  var originalData = ctx.args.data || {};
  var originalMethod = ctx.method;

  // Get shared method
  var modelSharedClass = app.remotes().classes().filter(function(item) {
    return item.name === modelName;
  })[0];
  var modelSharedMethod = modelSharedClass.methods().filter(function(item) {
    return item.name === method;
  })[0];

  // Change context data
  ctx.args.data = data;
  ctx.method = modelSharedMethod;
  ctx.methodString = modelSharedMethod.stringName;

  // Execute hooks
  var remoteObject = app.remoteObjects()[modelName];
  app.remotes().execHooks(when, modelSharedMethod, remoteObject, ctx, function(err) {

    // Restore context data
    var changedData = ctx.args.data;
    ctx.args.data = originalData;
    ctx.method = originalMethod;
    ctx.methodString = originalMethod.stringName;

    next(err);
  });
};
```

Example of using:

```
utils.execHooks(app, app.models.MyModel, model, 'before', 'create', ctx);
```